Understanding pinout of of motorised potentiometer (PRM 50KB-4)
I have a motorized potentiometer, labeled Z PRM 50KB-4

I believe I have found a datasheet for the component which contains the following diagram:

If I want to use the component as a voltage divider (so that I can connect to an analog input of a microcontroller), which pins would I use?
For reference, here are the pins with numbers


#1 is straight-forward and #4 is highly specialized. So why exactly did you pick the part where one side of the 2 potentiometer tracks is common?

@Lundin it's the component I have on hand. Will the common connection between the tracks prohibit me from using it as intended?

Depends on if you want 2 tracks or not and if so would they share a common ground or supply?

You would use the wiper and the ends like on a normal potentiometer.
The terminals with arrow symbols are the wipers. Then there are the midpoint terminals which you don't need. And then you have the ends. The ends of the two ganged pots are commoned, but nothing unusual if you simply use single channel of the pot for MCU ADC.

Which end to pick depends on if one wants increasing or decreasing resistance. Which in turn depends on the use-case. And as it happens one side of this particular pot is specialized, potentially making it unsuitable for one case or the other, if both tracks are to be used.

@Lundin Yes but for the use case given, you would use one channel and have supply and ground for the ends and the wiper to MCU.
